# Webcam stops working after a few minutes

Tags: drivers, webcam, asus-laptop

I am using an Asus U36JC with Chicony USB 2.0 Webcam.  It was working fine so far, but now whenever I use it, it stops after a few minutes. I reinstalled the drivers, I even formatted my PC but problem persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the program you're using it in crash? What do you mean by "it stops after a few minutes"?

Comment: No it doesn't crash. I use skype, or google plus, both starts fine, after a few minutes, or maybe less then a minute, image freezes. Also indicator light, which is next to camera freezes. When I close and restart the application, it says no camera found.

Comment: I know I've had issues with skype with the image freezing, but that had to do with slow internet speeds, so that's besides the point. Does the webcam have PnP capabilities or is this something you have to find on your own? Also, did you try rolling back the drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting BIOS to defaults seems to fix the problems. Not sure though.